# tar: What is the difference between jcvfh and -jcvfh?

Tags: posix, tar

When dropping the `-` I get what I want (a tar with all files included as expected) and when adding the `-` I get a binary file named `h`.

I understand that the file `h` is created because it appears after f, but I do not understand why it doesn't happen when I drop the `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like many of the traditional Unix commands, `tar` allows different option syntax styles:

1. UNIX options, which may be grouped and must be preceded by a dash.
2. BSD options, which may be grouped and must not be used with a dash.
3. GNU long options, which are preceded by two dashes.

The tar man page says *"the first argument to tar should be a function; either one of the letters Acdrtux, or one of the long function names."*

The `-f` option must be followed by the file name of the archive to be processed.

The order of your options is wrong, and gives different unexpected results depending on the platform and other circumstances. `c` should be the first option, and `f` must precede the filename.

```
tar -cjvhf name.tar.gz <path or file>
```

does the same as

```
tar cjvhf name.tar.gz <path or file>
```

Comment: Thanks! great answer!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it means ‘standard input’. It's used by some software (e.g. tar) when a file argument is required and you need to use stdin instead. It's not a shell construct and it depends on the program you're using. Check the manpage if in doubt!
Standard input is the argument to the -f option. In cases where - is not to be used, you can get away with using something like tar xvf /home/me/folder/yup or tar xvf /dev/stdin

Depending on the different platforms you use, do not expect this to mean ‘standard input’ globally. Since it's not interpreted by the shell, every program is free to deal with it as the program sees fit. In some places, it's standard output or something entirely different: on su it signifies ‘start a login shell’. In other places, it's not interpreted at all.

Comment: Thanks @Dup Step. I appreciate your answer, but i didn't completely understand it. What is the standard input? with the `-` or without?

Comment: Standard Input (or stdin) is the source of input data for a command line program. This falls under streams of data. Those streams being processes of either 1 input stream, 2 output streams, and standard error.

Comment: Thanks, but how is it related to the dash (`-`)?

Comment: It allows you to specify standard input or output rather than an actual file name. Just think of it as a flag. Not sure of another way to explain it. Sorry I wasn't any help. Good luck tho

Comment: Standard input has nothing at all to do with this question. The dash can only stand for the standard stream when it directly follows the `-f` option. Furthermore, for creating archives, the dash  would indicate *STDOUT*, not *STDIN*.